# How do i know a valie is statistically different from a group in excel

Tags: excel, math, statistics

I have a set of data in one column like:

5
4
7
4
25

I want to know if any of this values is statiscally different from the others in a certain confidence level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for a normal (bell curve) distribution which is pretty standard for just measuring things, about 2/3 of samples lie within one standard deviation away from the mean.  95% of samples are within 2, 99.7% within 3 and 99.99% within 4 ([Source](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StandardDeviation)).

To calculate the mean: sum up all the values and divide by the number of values you have.

To calculate the Standard Deviation:

[image: Standard Deviation Equation]

For each value (x), subtract (x - the mean).  Square that value.  Sum all of those values up.  Divide by the number of samples (n) that you have, minus 1.  Take the square root to get your standard deviation.

In order to find the upper and lower limits, for your mean, you must choose a confidence interval.  95% is pretty standard.  We're going to assume  a normal probability (a bell curve).

[image: Range Equation]

Your range is defined by the above formula.  The mean plus or minus a value.  S is your sample standard deviation that you just calculated.  N again is the number of samples.  t* is a "confidence number.  Look in table C [here](http://www.losmedanos.edu/Groups/Math/documents/FormulaSheetTable.pdf).  Look for your confidence value in the top row.  The degrees of freedom (first column) is n - 1.  The value in the table is your t* value.  Use these values to calculate your range for the mean (including upper and lower limits).

Depending on how "different" you want to think a value is from "the average," use the above guidelines.  A value could be different if it is [average + range value + 2*std deviation] or [average - range - 2*std deviation] if you define "different" as outside of 95% of the values.

Comment: Wow that was an excelent explanation, it helped me so much! Thank you so much! Good wishes and all the luck!

Comment: @Fábio Glad to help!  Good luck with your work.  Also, if you think I answered your question, consider marking it as the answer (check mark) :)